# Re-conforming to a protocol / conforming multiple times / overriding associated type

Tags: swift

Given the following protocol with an associated type:

```
protocol P {
    associatedtype T
    func f(t: T)
}
```

And the class `A` that conforms to protocol `P`:

```
class A: P {
    func f(t: String) {
        print(t)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to override the conformance to 'P' in a subclass 'B' so that we can change the associated type 'T' ?

```
class B: A, P { // Redundant conformance of 'B' to protocol 'P'
    func f(t: Int) {
        super.f("Hello")
        print(2 * t)
    }
}
```

Writing that `B` conforms to `P` is redundant and gives an error. 
B would be conforming to the protocol twice, which isn't possible even without subclassing.

I can think of scenarios where such a feature *might* be useful. Are there any reasons why this shouldn't be possible to do?

**Edit:**

What I'm asking is if there is any way to have `A` be `P<T>` and `B` be `P<U>` even if `B` is a subclass of `A`, i.e. override the associated type.

Comment: Your subclass already inherits the adoption of the protocol, so no need to do it again

Comment: @and for why its because of naming conflicts if you override the methods or variables..

Comment: This is particularly useful if there is a protocol extension that defines static functions that use the associated type.  @lescai-ionel did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your subclass already inherits the adoption of the protocol from its superclass, so there is no need to override the conformance of protocol in a subclass.

Reason:

```
protocol P {
    var name:String{get set}
}


class A:P {

    var name:String = "Swift"

}
class B:A {

    override var name:String{
        get{
            return "Hello"
        }set{

        }
    }
}
```

After conforming `class B` to `protocol P` you should implement the properties and methods.In normal cases, compiler will warn you to add the 
 required methods and properties..

But If that happens in this case,there will be conflict in name with the overridden ones..So this should not happen.And so you will get compiler error as

> Re-conforming to a protocol

Comment: Yes, but what I'm asking is if there is any way to have `A` be `P<T>` and `B` be `P<U>` even if `B` is a subclass of `A`.

Comment: I dont think there is a way because you cant use protocol methods inside base class without using overriding keyword. Your `func f(t: Int)` is own method of class B not from class A or protocol P